# example of department letter in support of waiving article processing charges

Tags: publications, peer-review, communication, fees

Looking for examples/ drafts of letters from department head in support for waiving/ getting discount on article processing charges. The journal is asking for such a letter stating that there is no funding for articles processing charges.

Any examples or certain language need to be included?

Thanks

Comment: Are you at a place where faculty publication is rare? Are you a student? Say more.

Comment: I am a student and yes faculty publication is less frequent than other places.

Answer (score 1):

The head or dean should just say something like they are sorry, but don't have any budget for student publications. They can add, if they like, how proud they are of you but that this is an unusual request.

I once had fees waived as a faculty member at a small school with constrained budgets. The publisher is used to seeing such requests. Usually they don't hold authors personally responsible for such fees and established researchers normally have some grant funds set aside for publication fees.

Reputable publishers are likely to be sympathetic.